# HTML Custom Audio Player - Stop multiple MP3's playing at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-audio

So I am creating audio elements using `document.createElement('audio')`.

I have this in a loop which actually creates around 20 audio files.

The issue I am having is that when I leave an audio file playing and click any other file to play, they both play at the same time.

How can I prevent the audio files from playing simultaneously?

*Note: All files work correctly when played, the issue is that files play at the same time unless you pause the previous one...*

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
// MP3 Player   

$('.player').each(function(index) {

    const formatTime = time => {
        const hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
        const remainder = time % 3600;
        const minutes = Math.floor(remainder / 60);
        const seconds = Math.floor(remainder % 60);

        const hh = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0');
        const mm = minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0');

        const ss = seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');


        return `${hh}:${mm}:${ss}`;
    }

    function updateTime() {
        var duration = this.duration;
        var currentTime = this.currentTime;
        var percentage = (currentTime / duration) * 100;
        playhead.style.width = percentage + '%';
        $('.player__duration-'+index).text(formatTime(duration));
      $('.player__currentTime-'+index).text(formatTime(currentTime) + ' / ');
    }         

    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', $('.active-song-'+index).attr('data-src'));   
    audioElement.setAttribute("class", 'audio-player-'+index);  

    var tl = new TimelineMax();
    tl.to('.player__albumImg-'+index, 3, {
        rotation: '360deg',
        repeat: -1,
        ease: Power0.easeNone
    }, '-=0.2');
    tl.pause();

    $('.player__play-'+index).click(function () {

        $('#prev').val($('#current').val());
        $('#current').val(index); 

        var to_pause = $('#current').val();  
        console.log(audioElement);

        if ($('.player-'+index).hasClass('play')) {
            $('.player-'+index).removeClass('play');
            audioElement.pause();
            TweenMax.to('.player__albumImg-'+index, 0.2, {
                scale: 1,
                ease: Power0.easeNone
            })
            tl.pause();
        } else {
            $('.player-'+index).addClass('play');
            audioElement.play();
            TweenMax.to('.player__albumImg-'+index, 0.2, {
                scale: 1.1,
                ease: Power0.easeNone
            })
            tl.resume();
        }  

    });


  var playhead = document.getElementById("playhead-"+index);
  audioElement.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateTime);   

    function updateInfo() {
        $('.player__author').text($('.active-song').attr('data-author'));
        $('.player__song').text($('.active-song').attr('data-song'));
    }
    updateInfo();

    $('.player__timelineBar-'+index).click(function (ev) {
        var $div = $(ev.target);
        var $display = $div.find('.playhead-'+index);

        var offset = $div.offset();
        var x = ev.clientX - offset.left;

        var ratio = x / $(this).width();
        var duration = audioElement.duration;

        var newCurrentTime = ratio * duration;
        audioElement.currentTime = newCurrentTime;

        audioElement.addEventListener("timeupdate", updateTime);

    });   

});
```

Comment: "Note: All files work correctly when played, the issue is that files play at the same time unless you pause the previous one..."

I think you just answered your own question.

Comment: Why you are creating 20 different audio elements inside for loop? Just generate one audio element and change its source when user clicks next. In your case you are adding event Listener inside for loop.

Comment: @DannyHobo - Not really, since I can't get the previous audio file to stop playing...

Comment: @pranavshinde - Because I am looping all the audio files to display on one page...

Comment: `" Because I am looping all the audio files to display on one page"` - you still really only need a single audio element

Comment: you can use `querySelectorAll` to find all the audio elements and iterate through and stopping any playing files before starting the new mp3

Comment: Keep the audio element just one. And create 20 UI element and pass unique identification when user clicks any play button. Based on that change the source of that single audio element

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - `        var audioFiles = document.querySelectorAll('audio'), i;

        for (i = 0; i < audioFiles.length; ++i) {
          console.log('HERE');
        }  ` - tried like this but it doesn't find any audio files